# jQuery: Getting div to display:none and staying that way when a third-party widget wants to come back and appear

Tags: javascript, jquery

Follow me on this....

I've got a Shopify store with a subscription widget being called. I'm trying to hide the widget (and div) when a button is clicked like this one:

```
$(".swatch-0").click(function() {
  $(".sub-widget").css("display", "none");
}
);
```

Don't get me wrong. This script works.

Normally.

However, this third-party widget keeps reappearing after a second or two. No matter what.

Actually, this happen on the first click of the button. On the second click the widget completely disappears and stays that way until another button is clicked. As it should. But on the second click?

Is there some way to enhance this script so that the widget stays hidden until a different button is clicked to make it display:block instead?